# Ajax call from Index.html to PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call to my PHP Script. I can echo the results from my data. php just fine. My question is how do I make the call from `index.html` to pull the table results in data.php.

```
<?php 

 $pullData = file_get_contents('https://api.rentcafe.com/rentcafeapi.aspx?requestType=apartmentavailability&APIToken=OTI4MjI%3D-eiBNyIvyQA8%3D&propertyCode=p0494361');

 $results = json_decode($pullData);

//Table columns
 echo '<table>
<tr>
<th>Apartment Name </th>
<th>Beds</th>
<th>Baths</th>
<th>Floor Plan Name</th>
<th>Minumum Rent</th>
<th>Maximum Rent</th>

</tr>';
//Iterate throught the API data and return only required columns
 foreach($results as $formatted_results){
    echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->ApartmentName.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->Beds.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->Baths.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->FloorplanName.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->MinimumRent.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->MaximumRent.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
  ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you're ok using jQuery, this is very easy ~ `jQuery('container-element-selector').load('path/to/data.php')`. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Where is your ajax code? `file_get_contents` is not ajax

Answer (score 0):

a simple get will do it.

```
$.get("data.php", function(data){   // GET data from page "data.php"
  $("#result").html(data);          // display data in a div with id "result"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider if your index.html contains below code then you can call ajax call in your script of html file. Here it is working code (consider index.html and date.php both are at the same place)

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="result">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get( "data.php", function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( data );
        });
    });
</script>
```

And data.php file contain code as given by you

data.php

```
<?php

 $pullData = file_get_contents('https://api.rentcafe.com/rentcafeapi.aspx?requestType=apartmentavailability&APIToken=OTI4MjI%3D-eiBNyIvyQA8%3D&propertyCode=p0494361');

 $results = json_decode($pullData);

//Table columns
 echo '<table>
<tr>
<th>Apartment Name </th>
<th>Beds</th>
<th>Baths</th>
<th>Floor Plan Name</th>
<th>Minumum Rent</th>
<th>Maximum Rent</th>

</tr>';
//Iterate throught the API data and return only required columns
 foreach($results as $formatted_results){
    echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->ApartmentName.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->Beds.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->Baths.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->FloorplanName.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->MinimumRent.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$formatted_results->MaximumRent.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
  ?>
```